# MVC cant upload file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Im fairly new to .NET Core MVC and trying to create a simple application where a user can upload a file and it saves to a home folder, currently i've followed a tutorial which at least seems to be a step in the right direction. however my post method isn't being hit when I click the submit button. does anybody have any insights as to why this is?

Here is my controller code:

```
 namespace GraduateOutcomesConverter.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }

 [HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> FileUpload(List<IFormFile> files)
    {
        long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);
        var filePaths = new List<string>();
        foreach (var formFile in files)
        {
            if(formFile.Length > 0)
            {
                var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
                filePaths.Add(filePath);

                using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
            }
        }
        return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePaths });
    }
```

And my View

```
 @{
ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
 }

 <div class="text-center">
<h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
<p>Please Upload An Excel File.</p>
<input type="file" name="datafile" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 
 15px; vertical-align: top; font-size:18px; background-color: white; margin- 
left:160px; margin-top:15px; width:250px; height:40px /">
</div>

 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp- 
controller="UploadFiles" asp-action="FileUpload">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-10">
    <p>Please Upload An Excel File.</p>
    <input type="file" name="files" multiple />
</div>
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
</div>
 </form>
```

Any help would be much appreciated
Thanks

Comment: `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp- 
controller="UploadFiles" asp-action="FileUpload">` controller name is invalid. You probably want to change it to `Home`

Comment: Perfect thanks, I've been fiddling around with it for an hour trying to get it to respond

Comment: Glad it helped. Post it as answer so you are free to mark it as answer (=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given  controller name to form element is Invalid. You probably need to change it to `Home`
Your current code

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp- 
controller="UploadFiles" asp-action="FileUpload">
```

It should be;

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp- 
controller="Home" asp-action="FileUpload">
```